# redirect_to category_post_path(@post)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have posts, and posts categories
Post belongs_to :category
Category has_many :posts
i want when I create new post rails redirect me to created post
but when i use in Posts controller

```
def create
        @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
        @post =  current_user.posts.build(post_params)
        if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Поздравляем Ваше задание опубликованно"
      redirect_to category_post_path(@post) 
  else
    render 'new'
  end
    end
```

This

```
redirect_to category_post_path(@post)
```

rails give me error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :category_id=>#, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

but i want if @post.save rails redirect_to created post

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet your routes look like this:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :posts
end
```

This create the URL helper category_post_path, but it needs a category and a post.

Try this:

```
category_post_path @category, @post
```

Comment: sorry in noob but now rails give error ArgumentError in PostsController#show
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) def show
  @posts = Post.find(params(:id))

Comment: Your problem is `params(:id)` should be `params[:id]`. Notice the square brackets. The full line: `@posts = Post.find(params[:id])`. If you want an explanation: `params` is a method that returns a hash, so `params[:id]` calls the params method, returns a hash, and then the value for index `:id` is retrieved.